# kafka _schemas topic when deleted, gets created without cleanup.policy

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am using Confluent Platform version 5.3.2 and in this i can see that _schemas topic is created with cleanup.policy as compact. Without this the schema registry will not be started. Now if i delete the _schemas topi, it will be created automatically, but without the cleanup.policy and because of this, if we restart the schema registry, it fails to start.

How can we make the _schemas topics to be created with cleanup.policy=compact when it is deleted and created automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Stop the registry. Delete the topic. Create the topic manually with the appropriate settings (compact, high replication, one partition). Never delete the topic again.

Or upgrade your registry version, and hopefully the topic will be created correctly